# Android 4.1 4.2 navigation tab not response ( include solution)

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

My application is running based on following libraries:

jQuery Version: 1.9.1
jQuery Mobile Version: 1.3.1

I made a table with 4 clickable cells:

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2YFV7/)

when I build my app in Phonegap, those tabs are working fine on iOS and Android 4.4, but 
doesn't work on Android < 4.4.

when click those cells, nothing happened.  I have to keep the data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" as if I remove it, the tabs are collapsed.

anyone experience the same issue? Sorry if I didn't put in all codes in as it's a large project.

```
<div class="sortbar" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
<table style="background-color:#555;border:none;">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="tick_top_menu">
            <td width="25%" onclick="alert('1')">tab1</td>
            <td width="25%" onclick="alert('2')">tab2</td>
            <td width="25%" onclick="alert('3')">tab3</td>
            <td width="25%" onclick="alert('4')">tab4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
.sortbar {


padding: 0px;


width: 100%;


left: 15px;


top: 64px;


height: 100px;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found this is related to hardware acceleration.

by applying following CSS on that navigation div solved my problem:

```
.androidpaintfix {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```